# Swift UITableView separator hidden until scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I have implemented a custom table view cell which appears but without the separator until you scroll.  In the viewDidAppear I have set the separator style, the label border is not overlapping the cell edges.  Help

Before Scrolling

[image]

After Scrolling

[image]

Larger Sim Window

[image]

On device testing

[image]

The pattern is MVVM with a custom cell.

Model

```
import Foundation

struct OAuthList {

    let providers: [String]

    init() {
        self.providers = OAuthProviders.providers
    }
}
```

View Model

```
import Foundation

struct OAuthListViewModel {

    var providerList: [String]

    init(providers: [String]) {

        self.providerList = providers
    }
}
```

LoginViewController

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var providerButtons = OAuthListViewModel(providers: OAuthProviders.providers)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.738589704, blue: 0.9438112974, alpha: 1)
        self.navigationItem.title = "LOGIN / SIGNUP"
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
        self.tableView.separatorColor = .white
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: TextCellIdentifier.textCellIdentifier)
        self.tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }
}

extension LoginViewController {

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return providerButtons.providerList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TextCellIdentifier.textCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.738589704, blue: 0.9438112974, alpha: 1)
        cell.buttonLabel.text = providerButtons.providerList[row]
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print(providerButtons.providerList[indexPath.row])

    }
}
```

Custom Cell

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    var labelText: String?

    var buttonLabel: UILabel = {
        var label = UILabel()
        return label
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: TextCellIdentifier.textCellIdentifier)
        self.addSubview(buttonLabel)
        buttonLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        buttonLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        buttonLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        buttonLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {

        if let labelText = labelText {
            buttonLabel.text = labelText
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to enlarge your simulator size.

Comment: Seems like it will be ok in real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the separator and simply add UIView to act as a separator inside your custom cells

Answer (score 0):

Enlarge your simulator window or try it on an actual device not sim.

When the sim window is small enough it can have a hard time displaying separators in a tableview since the separators are normally only 0.5pt in height.

A good indicator that the issue I mentioned above is occurring is when you scroll the tableview on the simulator and random separators start to appear while some are hidden. Which is what appears to be happening in your second screenshot.